# add a variable into an array in a specific position

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm trying to add a string into my array in the 3rd position because I need to do so for a loop I'm executing after it.

```
ArrayList<String> namesArray = new ArrayList<>(); 
namesArray.add(3, mString);
```

It gives  an out of bonds expection, is this not possible to do?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of the array?

Comment: show your full code

Comment: check it again please

Comment: The problem is due to that you are not specifying the size of the array.
That's why its size is 0.

Comment: You are declaring namesArray as an empty array with no size.  You're trying to add an element at position 3, but since there is no position 3 yet it's failing (as it should)

Comment: why do you want to add the value at the third position?

Comment: @pablobu I'm ordering an array<integer> in the order of its numbers, which is easy because I can give each number a position, and I need to match every number in that array with a string in this array, which I'l use each string position to order it. Hope that makes sense

Comment: if you already know the size of your array just use String[] namesArray = new String[size]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
arrayList.add(n, value);
```

the result is that after the `add`, `arrayList.get(n)` will have that value.  You're trying to arrange things so that `arrayList.get(3)` will be `mString`.  However, an `ArrayList` must be a list of consecutive elements; it can't be a "sparse array".  That is, for `arrayList.get(3)` to exist, `arrayList.get(0)`, `arrayList.get(1)`, and `arrayList.get(2)` must also exist.

I don't know what you want those values to be (maybe `null`?), but you do have to set them.  Java's `ArrayList` doesn't have an `add` method that automatically fills in the gap with a default value.  You can add 3 `nulls` to the array like this:

```
arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[3]));
```

Answer (score -1):

You should fill the array with empty string before index 3 like this:

```
namesArray.add("");
namesArray.add("");
namesArray.add("");
```

Then you won't get that exception